# divs in rails not aligning properly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css

I'd like to create a grid of these divs:

```
.category_result {
    width:178px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:180px;
    font-size:13px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

but when I insert the following lines into them, they are no longer aligned horizontally:

```
 <% @nonempty_category_companies[index].each do |cmp|%>
  <div class="category_company_name">
  <%= link_to company.company_name, :controller=>"companies", :action=>"show", :company_name =>"#{cmp.company_name}" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

any idea why? thank you.

btw:

```
.category_company_name {
    padding-top:7px;
    padding-left:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

========
edit: i am inserting the generated html

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML? If you're running Google Chrome (or have Firebug for FF), right click on your page and just copy over the generated HTML. I don't have RoR, so I can't help much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Ruby, so I'm not 100% sure I know what your generated HTML looks like, but I guess the issue is that you're not specifying `vertical-align`.

Try adding:

```
.category_result {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

And/or:

```
.category_company_name {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

See these links to understand why you need `vertical-align` with `display: inline-block`:

- http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html
- http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/